# How to fileOpen in C#(Win) to Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I've been trying to solve this problem for about a month with no luck.

My Android app needs to open files and also save them, to folders the app can access, like Documents.

This is part of my program in C#(Win):

```
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog1.Title ="Open File";
        try
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                string fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
            }
        }
```

But in Android, the closest I can come is this:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionGetContent);
            intent.SetType("text/plain");               
            intent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryOpenable);
            intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
            intent.PutExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_ADVANCED", true);
            intent.PutExtra("android.content.extra.FANCY", true);
            intent.PutExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_FILESIZE", true);
            StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Select file"), 0);
```

OR "Select file"), 1);

And while I can look at the files in various folders, I cannot open any of them. Once in a while when I click on a file I am prompted to select an app to open the file with and that works OK. But I see this prompt only occasionally.

I've been trying to make this work for about 2 months.

Thanks.
RON